# EF core. Bulk methods. Memory leak?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, bulkinsert

I have a program that transfers a table from 1 database to another. The table contains 24k records.

I create contexts using a factory.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<StackFlContext>(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StackFLDb"));
                x.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            });
            builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<StackUlContext>(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("StackULDb"));
                x.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            });
            builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<SabpekContext>(x =>
            {
                x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SabpekDb"));
                x.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
            });
```

I transfer the table like this:

```
public class IntegrationStackReferencesService : IIntegrationReferencesService
    {
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<StackFlContext> _stackFLContextFactory;
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<StackUlContext> _stackULContextFactory;
        private readonly IDbContextFactory<SabpekContext> _sabpekContextFactory;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public IntegrationStackReferencesService(IDbContextFactory<StackFlContext> stackFLContextFactory,
                                                 IDbContextFactory<StackUlContext> stackULContextFactory,
                                                 IDbContextFactory<SabpekContext> sabpekContextFactory,
                                                 ILogger logger
            )
        {
            _stackFLContextFactory = stackFLContextFactory;
            _stackULContextFactory = stackULContextFactory;
            _sabpekContextFactory = sabpekContextFactory;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task SyncStackReferences()
        {
            //Каждый блок защищён try catch поэтому если какой-то справочник не синхронизируется или будет ошибка,
            //то методы синхронизации других, всё равно будут выполнены
            using (var stackFlContext = _stackFLContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            using (var stackUlContext = _stackULContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            using (var sabpekContext = _sabpekContextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                await SyncTechStructureAsync<Models.Stack.StackFl.ВозможнаяСтруктура>(stackFlContext, sabpekContext);
            }
        }
private async Task SyncTable<T>(DbContext dbContext, IQueryable<T> list) where T : class
        {
            dbContext.Set<T>().Truncate();
            dbContext.Set<T>().BulkInsert(list);
            //await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

As a result, before the start of the transfer, I have the following memory consumption
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4P3O.png)

After transfer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UwyA.png)

I expect the memory should be cleared to +- frist value, no? what am i doing wrong? Contexts should have been cleaned up after "using". Why the memory is not cleared and what should I do to clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a sign of memory leak at all.

Garbage collection (GC) in .NET is not constantly freeing memory.  A quote from the documentation:

> Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is
> true:
>
> -- The system has low physical memory. The memory size is detected by
> either the low memory notification from the operating system or low
> memory as indicated by the host.
>
> -- The memory that's used by allocated objects on the managed heap
> surpasses an acceptable threshold. This threshold is continuously
> adjusted as the process runs.

I suggest you read more about GC [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/).

The memory consumption in your example has increased to merely 127 MB.
This is too little on any modern hardware and is not considered worth the effort by GC.

Comment: Thanks. I gave an example of synchronization of 1 directory. I have many more of them. My service is in a docker container. Now the docker container is eating 5GB of memory, do you mean that not all this memory is used, but just reserved? If I call the GC will this memory be cleared?

Comment: Well, you need to try for yourself.  I cannot reproduce your case.

Comment: thanks, I loaded my application and left it for the night with a cron of an hour with a table overflow and looked at the memory usage graph in the docker and indeed the collector cleans up the memory after some time.